# Google Elevation API resolution range and data sources

Tags: resolution, google-elevation-api

What is the minimum and maximum resolution of the elevation data from the Google Elevation API?

"A resolution value, indicating the maximum distance between data points from which the elevation was interpolated, in meters. This property will be missing if the resolution is not known. Note that elevation data becomes more coarse (larger resolution values) when multiple points are passed. To obtain the most accurate elevation value for a point, it should be queried independently." - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro

What data sources is it built from? SRTM1(30m US)? SRTM3(90m global) LiDAR? National Elevation Dataset (NED)?